# echo string based on specific month range throughout the year using php date function

Tags: php

I have a PHP website for a football club. I need to echo a string based on a specific month range throughout the year using the php date function.

For example, the current year is 2018 and the current football season is the 2017 / 2018 season. I need this to be like this until 31st May 2018. From the 1st June 2018 it needs to read 2018 / 2019 season up until 31st May 2019. This change needs to happen each year so next year after the 1st June 2019 it needs to read 2019 / 2020 season and so on for each year

Here is what I have so far but is this correct? It appears like it works

```
<?php
    if(date('m') >= 06) {
     $d = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 years'));
        echo   date('Y') .' / '.date('y', strtotime($d));
        } else {
     $d = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 years'));
 echo   date('Y', strtotime($d)).' / '.date('y');
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a lookt at carbon https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ with that you can easily achieve what you want with the between function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use `date('n')` to get month

n    Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros    1 through 12

```
if(date('n') >= 6){
    echo date('Y') .' / '. date('Y', strtotime('+1 year'));
}else{
    echo  date('Y', strtotime('-1 year')) .' / '. date('Y') ;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/lpvgW)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to work, I made just a couple of modification

```
if((int)date('m') >= 6) {     //cat to int before compare
  echo date('Y') .' / '.date('y', strtotime('+1 years'));  //short version
} else {
  echo date('Y', strtotime('-1 years')).' / '.date('y'); //short version
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll create a function to be able to re-use it:

```
function football_season() {
    if(date('m') >= 06) {
        $d = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 years'));
        $ret = date('Y') .' / '.date('y', strtotime($d));
    } else {
        $d = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 years'));
        $ret = date('Y', strtotime($d)).' / '.date('y');
    }
return $ret;}
```

I didn't change your code, it seems correct. I've just "functionalized" it.

Then, you'll just have to do `echo football_season();` to display "2017 / 18" with the current date.

…

Now, here is how I'll simplify this function:

```
function football_season() {
    if(date('n') >= 6)
            return date('Y').' / '.(date('y') + 1);
    else    return (date('Y') - 1).' / '.date('y');
}
```

( I often like to use a double tab when the `if` doesn't need `{ }`, so that the 2 possible solutions are aligned. )

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already returning correct value, I tried to make this more simple:

```
function getSeasonByMonth($month)
  {
      $year = date('y');
      if (date('m') >= $month) {
          $season = $year . '/' . ($year + 1);
      } else {
          $season = ($year - 1) . '/' . $year;
      }

      return $season;
  }
echo getSeasonByMonth(6);
echo getSeasonByMonth(2);
```